# Prove $e_A$ is an Extreme point of $B_A = \{a\in A: \|a\| \leq 1\} $ in a Banach algebra $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A$ be a  Banach algebra with identity  $e_A$

> prove that $e_A$ is an  extreme point of $B_A = \{a\in A: \|a\| \leq 1\} $

Recall that $x$ is an extreme point of $B_A$ if $x = \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2\in B_A$ implies that $x= x_1=x_2.$

**My attempt:**
let $x,y \in  B_A$, $t\in (0,1)$ and  $e_A=tx+(1-t) y$

it is easy to see that
$$\|x\|=\|y\|=1$$
therefore $$\|e_A-tx\|=\|(1-t) y\|<1  {\text{and }}\|e_A(1-t) y\|=\|tx \|<1$$

this implies that $$tx, (1-t) y \in Inv A$$
where $Inv A$ is the set of all invertible elements of $A$

I can't continue from here

Can I get some hints?

Comment: @ Idonknow , thanks

Comment: First of all, all extreme point of $B_A$ must have norm one. Clearly $e_A$ satisfies this. If we assume that $e_A = \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2\in B_A$, by triangle-inequality, $\|x_1\| = \|x_2\| = 1.$ I am not familiar with the definition of identity. Can you give its definition? Also, I think we don't need to resort to Krein-Milman Theorem. We should be able to prove it by definition.

Comment: $e_A$ is called identity if for all $a\in A  $ we have $e_A a=a e_A$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $1=\frac{1}{2}x_1 +\frac{1}{2}x_2$ with $x_1,x_2\in B_A$ where $1$ denotes the unit of $A$. Let $B_{A^*}$ denote the unit ball in $A^*$ and consider the set $Y=\{\psi \in B_{A^*}: \psi(1-x_1)=||1-x_1||\}$. It is convex and compact in the weak*-topology so by Krein-Milman $Y$ has an extremal point $\phi$. $\phi$ must be extremal even in $B_{A^*}$: if $\phi=\frac{1}{2}\phi_1+\frac{1}{2}\phi_2$ for $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in B_{A^*}$, the equation $||1-x_1||=\phi(1-x_1)=\frac{1}{2}\phi_1(1-x_1)+\frac{1}{2}\phi_2(1-x_1)$ along with $|\phi_1(1-x_1)|, |\phi_2(1-x_1)|\leq ||1-x_1||$ already implies that $\phi_1(1-x_1)=\phi_2(1-x_1)=||1-x_1||$ so $\phi_1, \phi_2\in Y$, which by extremality in $Y$ implies that $\phi_1=\phi_2=\phi$.

Now consider the decomposition $\phi=\frac{1}{2}\phi(\cdot x_1)+\frac{1}{2}\phi(\cdot x_2)$. Clearly $\phi(\cdot x_1),\phi(\cdot x_2)\in B_{X^*}$ so by extremality $\phi=\phi(\cdot x_1)$. In particular $\phi(1)=\phi(x_1) \rightarrow ||1-x_1||=\phi(1-x_1)=0$. Hence $x_1=x_2=1$.

Comment: @Dear Jonathan Hole,  thank you, your answer is very helpful